# How to uninstall ApacheDS 1.5.7 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: uninstallation, centos6, apacheds

I have installed ApacheDS 1.5.7 on CentOS 6.3. I want to uninstall it but it doesn't come with uninstaller. How do I uninstall ApacheDS 1.5.7 manually? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed apacheDs package then first search that package name using following command

```
rpm -qa *ApacheDS*
```

Then use following command to remove the package

```
yum remove package_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sandy_ws. I removed the directory manually to solve this. I will try as you suggested next time.